# Polylang : Interverting languages after development

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, navigation, admin-menu

My client asked me to switch French and English after the site was developed.

So I did two things:

Polylang > Languages: I selected English by default (asterisk on English)

Polylang > Settings: I disabled the option "Hide language information in web address for default language" to avoid rewriting hard URLs

Admin > Settings > Reading > The home page displays: I have selected the "home" which is my homepage in English.

Still, it does not work, It's always the French page that appears by default...

Best Regards